# How to reset the font color to black for the entire document?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, color

The font color of Contents section and List of Figures and List of Tables sections is blue in color in the existing preamble. How can I change this back to black?

Comment: Are you loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? If so, load it with the option `colorlinks=true` and `linkcolor=black`. Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem? It will also give us more detail on how to correct the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) which causes internal links to be coloured:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,% Colour links without boxes
  linkcolor=black}% Internal link colour is black

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

Other internal links may still be coloured differently. For this you need to set the specific link-attribute colour. Review the attributes listed in section **3.5 Extension options** in the [`hyperref` documentation](http://www.math.mun.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-90003.5).